# Selecting only the values that are in the 75th percent tile and are above a constraint

Tags: postgresql, return, limit

I'm trying to get this query to work properly...

```
select  salary from agent
where salary > 75000
ORDER BY salary ASC
LIMIT (select ROUND(count(salary) * .75) as TwentyFifthTile from agent)
```

some addition information about the rows:

- 166  rows – 25%
- 331 rows – 50%
- 497 rows – 75%
- 662 rows – 100%

These rows have salary 75,000 plus:

235 /  662 =   ~.35
.35 * 662 = ~235 rows.

I'm trying to get the above query to return back all the rows that have salary greater than 75,000 but are still in the first 497 rows.  When I run the above query it returns all the rows starting at 75,000 and limited by a 497 row return constraint.

I'm not sure how I can just return salaries of greater than 75,000 that are in the first 497 rows of the limit constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the total number of rows by the current row number to get this:

```
select salary
from (
  select salary,
         count(*) over () as total_count,
         row_number() over (order by salary) as rn
  from agent
  where salary > 75000
) t
where (rn / total_count::numeric) <= 0.75
order by salary asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Use row_number:

```
select salary, row_number() over (order by salary) row_num
from agent
where row_num < (select ROUND(count(salary) * .75) from agent)
and salary > 75000
```

Comment: @a_horse thx. For some reason your answer didn't appear till after I posted. Had I seen it, I wouldn't have bothered, but this is still a bit different in that it's terser.